# npm install issues on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: node.js, npm

I’m trying to install npm using the commands from here: http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm

Specifically, when I run:

```sh
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

This is the error I get...

```
node cli.js cache clean
TypeError: Object #<an EventEmitter> has no method 'on'
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sanjay/npm-1285345468/lib/utils/rm-rf.js:12:9)
at Module._compile (module:385:23)
at Module._loadScriptSync (module:397:16)
at Module.loadSync (module:296:10)
at loadModule (module:241:16)
at require (module:364:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sanjay/npm-1285345468/cli.js:14:10)
at Module._compile (module:385:23)
at module:413:20
at fs:52:23
make: *** [uninstall] Error 1
sanjay@sanjay-desktop:~$
```

Not sure if I am doing something silly, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's your node version? Seems that you have an old version... The event architecture has been overhauled massively in the newer versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That article is quite outdated.

[Since version 0.6.3, npm is bundled into node.js](https://github.com/isaacs/node/blob/master/ChangeLog#L1478).

Install the latest version of node from http://nodejs.org/ and you'll get npm aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error - upgrading to the latest stable version made it go away and I'm happily npm'ing.